# JBoss, exploded jar vs compact jar

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, deployment

I am working on Java 1.6, JBoss 5.1, EJB 3, and Hibernate 2. Every time I deploy the ear, if the jar is a compact one (non-exploded), application doesn't work. However when I explode the jar and then add it to the ear, the app works fine. Tried restarting Jboss, doesn't help.

The ear refers to numerous external jars; would the order of loading the jars be an issue?
How can I make JBoss load external jars followed by the app jars?

Thx.
WM.

Comment: What is the directory structure of your ear?

Comment: It's the standard directory structure - META-INF/, external jar, application jar, exploded directories. web.xml in the WEB-INF. No lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly does it fail? Nobody can help you if you don't tell the symptoms.

In any case, I'd be just happy that your application works, one way or another :)  There is nothing wrong with exploded jars, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The deployment doesn't go to completion. Fails to lookup the external jars.

Comment: bcprov-jdk16-144.jar.org.bouncycastle.crypto.macs] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at $Proxy173.<clinit>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Nikita, the above information was only one relevant. Not much information in the logs other than, deployment failure.

Comment: I removed application-specific information and tried google: turns out there are quite a lot of people with this exact problem. Does any post help?  http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%3CIMPORT-ALL%3ENON_EMPTY+org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)+at+java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)+at&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: True. None whatsoever. For now I am running the app with exploded jars and wars. Thanks for your help Nikita.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss's class loading mechanisms sometimes lead to unexpected issues.
I fixed this using a [classload-repository](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration)

```
<jboss-web>
   <loader-repository> 
      com.example:archive=unique-archive-name 
   </loader-repository> 
</jboss-web>
```